# Communication with Digital I/O Board with FTDI chip: Board designed by BCSIdeas

Tags: c++, c, gcc, io

I am trying to communicate to this RP0000xxxxS has 8/16/24/32 buffered Digital Inputs and 8/16/24/32 buffered Digital Outputs. The unit is
controlled through a USB connection. Reading and writing the DIO is done through a DLL.

I'm trying to make a simple program first that turns one LED ON/OFF. Then build from there to more difficult things. I managed to get my Raspberry Pi to read the device, so when its plugged in it shows up under lsusb.

I downloaded some example files off the web where I was supposed to:

- run make -n to see if all the files can be found.
- run make to build an executable named bcstest
- run make to build an executable named bcstest
- run the test 'bcstest'

As a result: LEDs on the board should scan back and forth
When I cd to the folder that I have these files saved in then type: `make -n`
It gives me an output of the following:

```
    gcc -Wall -03 -c bcstest.c
    gcc -Wall -03 -c rpsource.c
    gcc -Wall -03 -c bcstest bcstest.o rpsource.o -lftd2xx
```

I want to execute the bcstest file so I type in:
        gcc -bcstest.c -o bcstest

When I enter this in I get the following error:

In file included from rpsource.c:5:0:

```
       `ftd2xx.h:311:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or
        ‘__attribute__’ before ‘FT_Open’
        ftd2xx.h:317:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or
        ‘__attribute__’ before ‘FT_OpenEx’
        ftd2xx.h:324:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or
        ‘__attribute__’ before ‘FT_ListDevices’`
```

What's wrong? I just want to flash some LED's then detect some switches that I eventually connect to this I/O board. I downloaded most of the files from http://www.bcsideas.com/support_ia.php, then the drivers for FTDI from there website. However I guess because Linux is open source, I didn't need to bother with the FTDI drivers.

Comment: So which version of sample files are you trying to compile?

Comment: I expect that on line 311 of ftd2xx.h, you will see a function prototype that looks something like `FT_STATUS FT_Open()`.  If for some reason FT_STATUS was not defined, you might get a message like what you describe above.

Comment: So did you type `make` without the dry tun option (`-n`)? Please post actual command.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the bcstest.c file. I will see if I can change it to bcstest.cpp instead.

Comment: It's -O3 (capital o), not 0 (zero).

Comment: Also, the final GCC command looks like it should be `-o bcstest`, not `-c`, as you only put object files as args, nothing to compile, only link.